# What is the simplest way to make modules warnings fatal?

Tags: perl, warnings, perl-module, overwrite

By means of "mastering perl" I've overwritten the "encode"-function of the "Encode"-module. Is there a shorter way to make the encode-utf8-warnings fatal?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';
BEGIN {
    use Encode;
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *Encode::encode = sub ($$;$) {
        my ( $name, $string, $check ) = @_;
        return undef unless defined $string;
        $string .= '' if ref $string;
        $check ||= 0;
        unless ( defined $name ) {
            require Carp;
            Carp::croak("Encoding name should not be undef");
        }
        my $enc = find_encoding($name);
        unless ( defined $enc ) {
            require Carp;
            Carp::croak("Unknown encoding '$name'");
        }
        use warnings FATAL => 'utf8'; ###
        my $octets = $enc->encode( $string, $check );
        $_[1] = $string if $check and !ref $check and !( $check & LEAVE_SRC() );
        return $octets;
    }
}

use Encode qw(encode);
use warnings FATAL => 'utf8';

my $character;
{
    no warnings 'utf8';
    $character = "\x{ffff}";
#   $character = "\x{263a}";
}

my $utf32;
eval { $utf32 = encode( 'utf-32', $character ) };
if ( $@ ) { 
    ( my $error_message = $@ ) =~ s/\K\sin\ssubroutine.*$//;
    chomp $error_message; # where does the newline come from?
    say $error_message;
}
else {
    my @a = unpack( '(B8)*', $utf32 );
    printf "utf-32 encoded:\t%8s %8s %8s %8s  %8s %8s %8s %8s\n", @a;
}
```

subquestion: where does the newline in $error_message after the s/// come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your main question...  `use warnings FATAL => 'utf8';` is pretty short already; I don't think you're likely to find anything shorter.

As for the subquestion, `.` in a regex will, by default, match any character *except a newline*, so that substitution doesn't remove the final newline:

```
$ perl -e '$foo = "foo bar baz\n"; $foo =~ s/bar.*$//; print $foo . "---\n";'
```

prints

```
foo
---
```

To get `.` to match newlines, add the `/s` modifier to your regex:

```
perl -e '$foo = "foo bar baz\n"; $foo =~ s/bar.*$//s; print $foo . "---\n";'
```

prints

```
foo ---
```

Comment: Do I have to overwrite the encode-function to make the utf8-warnings fatal?

Comment: @sid_com: Yes, you do, *if* you're going to do it via `use warnings FATAL` because `use warnings` is lexically-scoped and will *never* affect code in another file. You could, however, start from `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die @_; };` and then add a condition so that it will only die on UTF-8 errors - but you'll probably have to detect them by inspecting the error message, which is fraught with dragons.